# Como saber que o arquivo chegou ao final com FileReader()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou fazendo um sistema que quando o arquivo acaba de ser lido abre o próximo arquivo, os arquivos são MP3 e queria tocar uma sequencia de musicas sempre que uma terminar. Como fazer isso com FileReader()?

Tentei `reader.onloadend = (function() {});` mas não deu certo, assim que o arquivo é carregado ele já executa a função, preciso que execute só quando ele terminar de ser lido...

Código até o momento:

```
<input type="file" id="file" multiple="multiple">
<button id="openNewSessionButton" disabled>Open New Room</button><br />
<script>
var connection = new RTCMultiConnection('stream');
connection.session = {
    audio: true,
    oneway: true
};

// connect to signaling gateway
connection.connect();

// open new session
$("#openNewSessionButton").click(function() {
    connection.open();
});

$("#file").change(function() {
var fileA = this.files[0];
var fileB = this.files[1];
readFile3(fileA);
});

function readFile3(file){
    var file1 = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var context = new AudioContext(),
        buffer;

    var playAudioFile = function (buffer) {
        var source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.start(0); // Play sound immediatel
        var destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
        source.connect(destination);

                        connection.attachStreams.push(destination.stream);
                        connection.dontAttachStream = true;
                        $("#openNewSessionButton").removeAttr('disabled');



            var current2 = source.buffer.duration;
            var n = Math.floor(current2);
            var b = n * 1000;

            var timer = setTimeout(function(e) {

            readFile3(fileB); //THIS LINE ? IS CORRECT ?

            }, b);
    };

    var loadAudioFile = (function (url) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('get', file1, true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';


        request.onload = function () {
                context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(incomingBuffer) {

                        playAudioFile(incomingBuffer);

                     }
                );
        };

        request.send();

    }());
</script>
```

Comment: Que estranho... Tenho um [exemplo no meu site](http://carlosrafaelgn.com.br/GraphicalFilterEditor/), e utilizo `readAsArrayBuffer` com o evento `onload` e tudo funciona bem. O arquivo já está na memória quando `onload` é executado. Dá uma olhada na função `loadIntoMemoryAndPlay`, na linha 294 da página (testado OK em Chrome, Firefox e Opera).

Comment: Você precisa mesmo utilizar um `FileReader()`? Pode tocar o áudio via outro método? Se sim, dá uma olhada na função `prepareStreamingAndPlay` do [meu exemplo](http://carlosrafaelgn.com.br/GraphicalFilterEditor/), linha 314 do arquivo.

Comment: Só um detalhe... andei editando [o exemplo](http://carlosrafaelgn.com.br/GraphicalFilterEditor/), e agora os números das linhas são 302 (`loadIntoMemoryAndPlay`) e 339 (`prepareStreamingAndPlay`) :)

Comment: Oi @carlosrafaelgn, vi seus exemplos e achei bem bacana e até mudei o sistema que eu estava usando, mas não consigo passar para a próxima faixa quando a primeira termina, editei a pergunta e adicionei o código que estou usando agora...abraço...

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn consegui algum resultado...vou postar a resposta...

Comment: Curioso, mesmo! Parece um bug ainda não resolvido... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui obter resultados e estou trabalhando no sistema, o erro era bem simples, estava tentando rodar a função readFile3(); com a variável não setada, só precisei colocar a função dentro do $("#file").change(); onde a variável estava setada, ficando assim:

```
<input type="file" id="file" multiple="multiple">
<script>

var connection = new RTCMultiConnection('stream');
connection.session = {
    audio: true,
    oneway: true
};


// connect to signaling gateway
connection.connect();


$("#file").change(function() {

$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');

var fileA = this.files[0];
var fileB = this.files[1];
readFile3(fileA);


function readFile3(file){
    file1 = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var context = new AudioContext(),
        buffer;

    var playAudioFile = function (buffer) {
        var source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.start(0); // Play sound immediatel
        var destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
        source.connect(destination);

                        connection.attachStreams.push(destination.stream);
                        connection.dontAttachStream = true;
                        connection.open();


            var current2 = source.buffer.duration;
            var n = Math.floor(current2);
            var b = n * 1000;

            var timer = setTimeout(function(e) {

            connection.close();
            readFile3(fileB);
            $("#result").html("TRANSMITINDO 2");

            }, b);
    };

    var loadAudioFile = (function (url) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('get', file1, true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';


        request.onload = function () {
                context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(incomingBuffer) {

                        playAudioFile(incomingBuffer);

                     }
                );
        };

        request.send();

    }());
};
});
</script>
```

A chava é um Timeout com o tempo da mp3, conforme explicado aqui : http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/01/Web-Audio-FAQ

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma diferença entre *carregar* e *executar*.

Acredito que você já tenha conseguido *carregar* corretamente todos os arquivos, em sequência, para a memória. A funcionalidade do FileReader acaba aí; o JavaScript passa a ter acesso aos bits dos arquivos escolhidos pelo usuário.

A próxima etapa, que é efetivamente *executar* estes arquivos, é onde você está com dificuldades. E as notícias não são boas. Mesmo que você utilizasse o evento correto (que por sinal é o `onended()`, no seu AudioBuffer `buffer`, como no código que segue), parece que ele não está muito bem implementado nos navegadores ainda. Uma pena! Segue a alteração para você experimentar:

```
// Import callback function that provides PCM audio data decoded as an audio buffer
context.decodeAudioData(e.target.result, function (buffer) {
    // ...
    // Aqui vai a modificação:
    buffer.onended = function(){
        console.log("Uma música acabou... Iniciar a próxima?");
    }
    // ...
});
```

Se por um milagre isso funcionar, seria bom reportar de volta para o resto do pessoal saber que já está implementado, e em QUAL navegador :)

Comment: Oi @Rui Pimentel, Fiz alguns testes e realmente não funciona...continuo atrás de uma solução...abraço!